# What is data-gr-c-s-loaded=“true” attribute added to my code

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML code and I came across this in the body tag. I do not know from where this came:

```html
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded attribute="true">...</body>
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Do you use Grammarly? Grammarly adds this tag automatically.

> It looks like it is the Grammarly 79 extension that adds that data attribute 34. Likely use for some internal check (like to verify it has loaded into the page).

See https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/what-is-data-gr-c-s-loaded-true-attribute/373769

You can also check with `if (document.body.dataset.newGrCSLoaded)`, which is the newest data attr for Grammarly if the user has Grammarly installed.